# Jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I'm using the following script below to add "+1 day" to second field (#returningdate). But if a user chooses on the #leavingdate 12/31/2009 they would get a #returningdate of 12/32/2009 instead of 01/01/2010. This happens with any end month date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
        $("#leavingDate").change(function(){
             $("#returningDate").datepicker( 'setDate' , "+1 day" );

             var date = this.value.split("/");
             $("#returningDate").val(date[0]+'/'+(parseInt(date[1])+1)+'/'+date[2]); 
        }).datepicker();
        $("#returningDate").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in javascript Date object to manipulate dates:

```
  $(function() {
        $("#leavingDate").change(function(){
             $("#returningDate").datepicker( 'setDate' , "+1 day" );

             var date = new Date( Date.parse( this.value ) );
             date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
             $("#returningDate").val(date.getMonth()+'/'date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear()); 
        }).datepicker();
        $("#returningDate").datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: I tried you're example but I can't seem to get the calendar to launch now. 
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#leavingDate").change(function(){
             $("#returningDate").datepicker( 'setDate' , "+1 day" );

             var date = new Date( Date.parse( this.value ) );
             date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
             $("#returningDate").val(date.getMonth()+'/'date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear()); 
        }).datepicker();
        $("#returningDate").datepicker();
  });
   
      </script>

Comment: My bad. Your solution works perfectly. Some characters didn't copy over correctly on my end.